# Why a sub folder is not downloaded when installing the package?

Tags: react-native, npm-install

I am trying to install a package from a public repo, it get downloaded into `node_modules` but I've noticed that the `ios` folder into that package is not downloaded, and only the android is downloaded.

Of course, I need both ios and android folders of the package.

Any idea why?

Comment: Is there an `.npmignore` file with an ignore specified for `ios`?

Comment: yes, actually, I can show it here: https://github.com/RemodelingComDev/react-native-device-info/blob/master/.npmignore

Comment: It doesn't have a folder titled `ios` but it does have the ios project `RNDeviceInfo.xcodeproj`  and accompanying files in the `RNDeviceInfo` directory.

Comment: How come? isn't it that one: https://github.com/RemodelingComDev/react-native-device-info/tree/master/ios